# What is the equivalent of ifconfig interface ip_address for ip command?

Tags: command-line, networking, ip

I'm looking for an exact replacement of `ifconfig <interface> <ip_address>` command using the ip command.

For example, if I want to change eth0's IP address to 10.0.0.1 (not caring about the netmask), I can just type:

```
ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.1
```

For the ip command though, I've looked around a lot and anything I can find is just adding or removing a network, not modifying the current one. So, to modify the current network, I end up having to use the following (or similar) script:

```
new_ip=$1
ip_addr=`ip addr show eth0 | grep "inet" | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $2}'`

ip -4 addr delete $ip_addr dev eth0
ip -4 addr add $new_ip dev eth0
```

Because if I don't do it this way, when the primary interface ip is deleted later on, it takes all the secondary ip addresses with it.

I'm doing this from inside a program and there are too many system calls that could go wrong here. Is there a way to do this without having to use so many commands?

`ip addr change` and `ip addr replace` also does the same thing:
[image]

<sub>Note: I can add any open source program into the system as I want. So, don't shy away from solutions that use other open source programs.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`ip addr change ...` is what you are looking for.

do `ip addr help` to see details

Edit: For future readers - this is wrong answer, see comments.

Comment: That just gives me a secondary IP address.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Looks like change and replace allow to change just flags, not IP itself.